# Can't access on public folder Firebase Hosting

Tags: node.js, express, firebase-hosting

I use canvas with express.js and firebase hosting , it's working fine in localhost when run `firebase serve` but when I deployed the canvas Couldn't load image

I have tried put the public in functions folder and outside but it didn't work

no my project structure is

```
--project(root)
----functions(sub folder)
------routes(sub folder)
------public(sub folder)
--------images(sub sub folder)
------app.js(app server)
```

I have print the __direname in routes folder to show where I'm

```
__dirname = /srv/routes
```

and the image path to load and it's wrong is

```
"src":"../public/images/default/B-9.png"
```

> I have tried ../../public and /images also both not working

firebase.json is

```
    {
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix ./functions/ run lint"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./functions/public",

    "rewrites":[
      {
        "source":"**",
        "function":"app"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and I defined  public folder in express.js like that

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
```

I try access image by URL from browser it's working like

```
https://angular6test.firebaseapp.com/images/AV.png
```

but when I try to load this url from my canvas code also it's couldn't access on image

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?